# Shortcut on Desktop takes to application folder, not running the application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use Setup project.  Want my setup to create a desktop shortcut with my application.
I donot understand how to do it.  Clicked on User's desktop, I created Shortcut to User's desktop, changed the properties Target and Working Folder as 'Application Folder'
But it does not connect with MyApplication.exe
When I ran the setup and tested Desktop short cut, it took me to the folder where application was installed, instead of running the application.

How to make the application run using this shortcut?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear, but this

> changed the properties Target and Working Folder as 'Application Folder'

suggests you have set `Target` as `Application Folder`. `Target` should instead be set as your `exe` - by setting `Target` you set what the shortcut actually *does*.

Answer (score 1):

I must be late but since this question has no answer i think i should post the solution
i faced same problem but after little tick tac here and there solved this issue
here you should do

1. select the shortcut in user's desktop folder, look for the property of that shortcut "Target" it should be "Primary Output" if not then delete the shortcut
2. right click and "create new shortcut"
3. in "select item in project" window , open Application Folder
   select "Primary output from 'your_project_name ' (Active)"

and done 
(change shortcut name description icon as per your need)